# Cannot find welcome window in Bionic Beaver DVD

Tags: system-installation, dvd

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Desktop (Bionic Beaver) on an HP Laptop 15-da0xxx. It's currently running Windows 10 Home.

I downloaded ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop, and burned a DVD as described at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1.

When I boot the DVD, it boots directly up to the Ubuntu desktop. It never gives me the opportunity to install. The welcome window (shown at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#2) never appears.

I tried the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck in hopes of using the CD menu to install. However, the CD menu never appeared.

I checked the disk contents from Windows, as suggested at 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD#The_DVD_was_not_burned_properly. The disk contents look reasonable, although different from what's shown in the documentation. Here's what I found:

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LAhj.png)

I am running out of ideas. Is there an alternative method to install from a DVD? Or should I consider installing from some alternative source, as described at 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD?

Thank you,

Caroline

Comment: When it boots to the desktop, is there a shortcut to the installer on the desktop? If it's booting to the standard live session, it will, and you can install it that way.  If it doesn't there is something wrong with your dvd.

Comment: When I boot the live session, the desktop looks like this.  https://imgur.com/a/pKam6jy (I added the arrow)

Comment: Yes, my desktop does have a link like that. So I can just run it, huh? I didn't know it was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, you can accept it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your live session is working properly, there should be a link to the installer on the desktop.

[image]